# Remove rows of data based on data in the combination of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code below produces the left block of data

[image]

It gives me the entire subset however I only need to see: For the same SATNR-VKORG combination where ALL Variant_Status is I2. If any of the Variant_Status is NOT I2, then do not show the entire SATNR-VKORG combination. My final output should only be the first two lines in the data below whereas all the other rows do not qualify.

I can't figure out how to do this but I'm thinking to use a count function like the right block to concat the SATNR-VKORG and SATNR-VKORG-Variant_Status and do a count of each unique combination. For the same SATNR-VKORG combination, if the two counts are identical then that means display else do not show. Even that I don't know how to code it, anyone help or have any better idea?

```sql
SELECT TOP (1000) 
 MARA.MATNR, 
 MARA.SATNR, 
 MARA.ATTYP, 
 MARA.MTART, 
 MARA.MSTAE, 
 MARA.LVORM, 
 MVKE.VMSTA as Variant_Status, 
 MVKE.VTWEG, mvke.VKORG, MVKE2.
 VMSTA as Generic_Status, 
 MVKE2.VTWEG, MVKE2.VKORG, 
 mara.satnr + mvke.vkorg as concated

from [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MARA AS MARA
JOIN [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MVKE AS MVKE ON MARA.MATNR = MVKE.MATNR
JOIN [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MARA AS MARA2 ON MARA.SATNR = MARA2.MATNR
JOIN [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MVKE AS MVKE2 ON MARA2.MATNR = MVKE2.MATNR

WHERE MARA.MTART != 'ZODE' 
  AND MARA.ATTYP in (02) 
  AND MARA.LVORM = '' 
  AND MVKE2.VTWEG = '34' 
  AND MVKE.VTWEG = '34' 
  AND MVKE.VKORG=MVKE2.VKORG 
  and mvke2.vmsta != 'I2'

ORDER BY MARA.SATNR,MVKE.VKORG,MVKE2.VKORG, MARA.MATNR
```

Comment: This is SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Convert the query to CTE. Add an expression like `SUM(CASE WHEN Variant_Status = 'I2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [SATNR-VKORG])` to output list. In main query select only those rows for which this additional; expression is above zero. Or backward - summarize `Variant_Status != 'I2'` and select rows with zero. Aim-dependent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT TOP (1000) 
 MARA.MATNR, 
 MARA.SATNR, 
 MARA.ATTYP, 
 MARA.MTART, 
 MARA.MSTAE, 
 MARA.LVORM, 
 MVKE.VMSTA as Variant_Status, 
 MVKE.VTWEG, mvke.VKORG, MVKE2.
 VMSTA as Generic_Status, 
 MVKE2.VTWEG, MVKE2.VKORG, 
 mara.satnr + mvke.vkorg as concated,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Variant_Status <> 'I2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SATNR, VKORG) marker 
 
from [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MARA AS MARA
JOIN [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MVKE AS MVKE ON MARA.MATNR = MVKE.MATNR
JOIN [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MARA AS MARA2 ON MARA.SATNR = MARA2.MATNR
JOIN [dgSAP_PRD].dbo.MVKE AS MVKE2 ON MARA2.MATNR = MVKE2.MATNR

WHERE MARA.MTART <> 'ZODE' 
  AND MARA.ATTYP in (02) 
  AND MARA.LVORM = '' 
  AND MVKE2.VTWEG = '34' 
  AND MVKE.VTWEG = '34' 
  AND MVKE.VKORG=MVKE2.VKORG 
  and mvke2.vmsta <> 'I2'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE marker = 0
ORDER BY SATNR, VKORG, VKORG, MATNR
```

Comment: Thank you. This logic makes sense however I am getting error with the ' SUM(Variant_Status != 'I2') OVER (PARTITION BY SATNR, VKORG) marker ' line saying incorrect syntax near '!' and also PARTITION is highlighted with error. I can't seem to figure out the issue with that.

Comment: @Yundengogo Edited.

Comment: Hi @Akina, still the same issue, I am using SQL server mgmt studio v15.0 - could it be something to do with that?

Comment: @Yundengogo This is impossible - there is no citated code fragment in edited code. Provide complete and inchanged error message. Well, I'll edit one more time, wait... done.

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Ambiguous column name 'SATNR'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Ambiguous column name 'VKORG'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'Variant_Status'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'VTWEG' was specified multiple times for 'cte'. @Akina

Comment: @Yundengogo (1,2) `(PARTITION BY MARA.SATNR, MARA.VKORG)`. Or maybe MARA2? (3) `SUM(CASE WHEN MVKE.VMSTA <> 'I2' THEN`. (4) `MVKE2.VTWEG AS VTWEG2`.